# Passing variable created from Regular Expression Extractor to HTTP Cookie Manager does not work in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, http, regex

1. I've added a regular expression extractor as a child element of the `HTTP request`
2. From the regular expression extractor I've created a new variable called `variabletest`.

| Name of created variable: | variabletest |
| --- | --- |
| Regular Expression: | "id":"(.+?)" |
| Template | $1$ |
| Match No: | 1 |

3. I add Debug sampler to ensure it return the correct output.

   - Request 1

     - Regular `Expression Extractor` (Name of created variable: `variabletest`)
     - Debug sampler
   - Request 2
   - HTTP Cookie Manager
4. Then, I added a `HTTP Cookie Manager` at the bottom of the test plan. Where it configured as below.

| Name: | Value | Domain | Path: | Secure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| afiliation | ${variabletest} | localhost:8080 | /sample |  |

For the Request Body of request 1,2,3...
instead of showing the correct extracted variable value, it just show `afiliation=${variabletest}`

**When** I run the test, the `${variabletest}` is show as empty value, it seems like it doesn't consider the extracted variables.

**Then**, when I increase the loop count to `2`, I noticed, that the extracted variable only available for use in the second iteration of the test plan and not in the first iteration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I can think only of incorrect placement of the Regular Expression Extractor, i.e. check [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) chapter

If you have the Regular Expression Extractor at the same level as your Samplers - it will be executed after **each Sampler** so

1. It's executed after 1st HTTP Request sampler and extracts the variable normally
2. It's executed after Debug Sampler and fails to extract the variable **overwriting** the previous variable value with the empty or default value

So I think if you move it to be the child of the 1st HTTP Request sampler it should resolve your issue.

[image]

It also appears that you're using regular expressions to fetch the id from JSON response which is not the best idea as [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language), maybe it worth considering migrating to [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. I've tried and unfortunately, it still return an empty value eventhough i can see the correct output being displayed in the debug sampler. Perhaps do you have any idea or what could be the problem?